# GET parent id in nested resource

Tags: php, web-services, rest, yii2

Im trying to get all comments under post `#{any nos.}` , but I'm stuck on how can I get the `post_id` when I hit the URI below. for example post #1

on GET URI : `/posts/1/comments/`

on CommentController :

```
public function actions() {
   $actions = parent::actions();
   unset($actions['index']);
   return $actions;
}

public function actionIndex($post_id)
{
  return Comments::find()->where(['post_id' => $post_id])->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of _urlManager in yii2

```
return [
   'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
   'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
   'showScriptName'=>false,
   'rules'=>[
      // url rules
      'posts/<post_id:\d+>/comments' => 'posts/index',

     ]
 ];
```

Comment: I am using same kind of url in `backend/company/id/details` and this file resides in `/backend/config/_urlManager.php` .... let me know whether it works for you or not